# Use of the indefinite article with the object of a preposition

Tags: prepositions, indefinite-article

Here are some examples of prepositional phrases:

1. for better education
2. for better healthcare
3. for better security
4. for **a** better life

Is is right to use *a* in the last case?

Comment: It's perfectly acceptable, though it does personalize the last phrase a bit (in comparison to the others). You could also say, "For better lives."

Comment: You could also use the indefinite article in #1. It depends whether you are using "education"  as a count noun or not.

Comment: A preposition is followed by a noun phrase. Whether a noun phrase has an article ('a/an' or 'the') depends on whether the noun is countable or uncountable. If the noun can be either countable or uncountable, you need to decide how you are using it in this sentence. 'Education' can be countable or uncountable: you can say 'For better education' or 'For a better education' (specifically). 'Healthcare' and 'security' (in this sense) are uncountable. 'Life' can be countable or uncountable, and in your example is countable, so needs the 'a' (or becomes countable because you use the 'a').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly acceptable. The headline of this question makes me wonder if you think there is something grammatically wrong with using an indefinite article in a prepositional phrase. If that were the case, we couldn't have phrases like "in a bind," "for a change," or "with a friend."